# Text processing. Find a datetime in a line, copy the datetime, paste it further up the line

Tags: datetime, vim, awk, copy-paste, text-processing

I have a SQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO public.sensor_data (doc) VALUES ('{"x": 1, "readerId": "63", "locationSensorId": "13", "lux": "0", "locationCounter": "3", "alarm": "0", "rssi": "436", "datetime": "2017/07/10 17:01:44.539910", "magnet": "5", "y": 1, "uniqueName": "hive", "v": 1, "agesent": "3741337710", "sensorId": "4000043", "z": 1, "movement": "65535"}')
```

It actually needs to include a column named created_at, and another value after the JSON. This must be the value of the datetime key in the JSON ('2017/07/10 17:01:44.539910').

I can add the necessary sql in vim, parenthesis etc after the first value.

I cannot figure out how to copy that datetime value per line and paste it further up the line to be within the sql value parenthesis (' '). Is there some magical regular expression out there?

Comment: Sorted this with a messy hack. Saved the file as a csv by changing its extension. That encases everything in double quotes when you change it back which is annoying but fixable. Because it was a JSON everything appeared in columns, so I cut the datetime column out and put it at the end. Now I'm using find and replace to sort the (' ')

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can solve this with a regex like this:

```
s/datetime":\s\(".\{-}"\),\(.*\))$/datetime": \1,\2, created_at: \1)/g
```